# React child calling parent handler function, does parent have to pass `this` to child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance

What I have is a list of items, where each of the `Item` Component have a delete button that will make a call to the `deleteItem` function in the `List` component to update its state. The `deleteItem` function will need the parent instance bound to it to call `this.setState`.

Currently I'm passing `parent={this}` along with `deleteHandler={this.deleteItem}` when the `List` renders the `Item`. So that when the `Item` calls the handler, it will have access to the parent instance.

```
onClick={this.props.deleteHandler.bind(
    this.props.parent,
    this.props._key
)}
```

But this feels unnecessary, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve what I want to do. (ie. some kind of built in linkage between child and parents, or a better way to pass/call the function)

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJEOro?editors=0011)

**Child Component**

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                {this.props.value}
                <button
                    className="delete"
                    onClick={this.props.deleteHandler.bind(
                        this.props.parent,
                        this.props._key
                    )}
                >
                    x
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }
    renderItem(item) {
        return (
            <Item
                key={item.key}
                value={item.value}
                _key={item.key}
                deleteHandler={this.deleteItem}
                parent={this}
            />
        );
    }
    addItem() {
        // ...
    }
    deleteItem(key) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: prevState.items.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.key !== key;
            })
        }));
    }
    render() {
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
            items.push(this.renderItem(this.state.items[i]));
        }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ul>{items}</ul>
                <button className="addItem" onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>
                    Add Value
                </button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing your entire parent instance to the `Item` component, you could pass a function that the child will call to remove itself in the parent.

Comment: @Tholle I am passing the function to the child with deleteHandler=deleteItem. But how do I call that function? If I just call it normally, this.setState won't be defined as this will refer to window.

Comment: You could bind it in the constructor with `this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);` or make `deleteItem` into an arrow function with `deleteItem = () => { ... };`

Comment: Ahh yes that does the trick. It looks like i was a little confused about the functionality of `bind` and wasn't too familiar with the specifics of the arrow notation. thanks!